# Is the determinant of $A$ is equal to the product of its eigenvalues for vector spaces over any field?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have seen a proof of this in Lax (pg. 65, Theorem 3) but it relies in the fact that we can factor the characteristic polynomial as 
$$
p_A(s) = \prod_{i=1}^n(s-a_i)
$$
where $a_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. But doesn't this factorization require the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) which is only proven for $\mathbb{C}$? Is the statement supposed to hold for vector spaces over any field?

Comment: It holds for vector spaces over any algebraically closed field, if you count the eigenvalues with (algebraic) multiplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it only hold in $\mathbb{C}$ : just consider to convince you $$R_{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},$$ with $\chi_R=X^2+1$ but if you take its spectra over $\mathbb{R}$ it is the empty set. As Servaes said, when we talk about eigenvalues we directly take them in an algebraic closure.

Comment: I assume $\operatorname{Sp}$ is referring to the spectrum of the matrix, its set of eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes exactly, I don't know if it is a correct notation ?

Comment: I don't either, my comment was primarily in case the OP wasn't familiar with spectra (I'm only vaguely familiar).

Comment: I will edit that so, thank you !

Comment: @Baloown. Thank you for the answer. What is a spectra? Additionally, in the comments to my question, Servaes says "It holds for vector spaces over any algebraically closed field". Yet you said it only holds in $\mathbb{C}$. These seem to be at odds. Which one is true?

Comment: You're welcome. Spectra over $K$ of a matrix $M$ is the set of the eigenvalues of $M$ taken in $K$ : in my example, spectra over $\mathbb{R}$ was $\varnothing$ whereas spectra over $\mathbb{C}$ was $\{+i,-i\}.$ I answered that it only holds in $\mathbb{C}$ because I assumed that you were working in $\mathbb{R}$ (without reasons indeed), but it is Servaes who is right.